# How do I associate IdentityDbContext with two databases?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have `ASP.Net Core` command-line application where I try to copy data from one database from another. So ideally, I would want to have something like this

```
services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FromConnection")));
services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ToConnection")));
```

Obviously, this won't work since the type in the generic is the same. *If* I could do something like this:

```
var fromContext = new IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>();
var toContext = new IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>();
services.AddDbContext(fromContext, options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FromConnection")));
services.AddDbContext(toContext, options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ToConnection")));
```

It's a small utility program; so I can compromise (somewhat) on the dependency injection - is there any way to accomplish this?

In this case I am trying to copy roles and claims from Identity tables; so the same problem is with `IdentityRole` and `IdentityRoleClaim` classes - but the first step is to set up `DbContext` separately.

UPDATE: If I were to use derived classes from `DbContext` like this:

```
public class IdentityFromDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser> { ... }
public class IdentityToDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser> { ... }
```

I then need to have the following:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>()
```

And if I were to derive `IdentityFromUser` etc. I would get a problem that I need to modify the application model itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered having separated contexts that inherit from your `MyDbContext`?

i.e. `OldDbContext : MyDbContext` and `NewDbContext : MyDbContext`.

Comment: I want to say *I did and I got the problem*; but now I am thinking that the problem was more because I also had `FromIdentityRole` etc. and that gave me an error related to discriminator. I didn't try to *just* inherit `MyDbContext`. Let me try before I accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using two DbContext to connect two databases instead of copying data to the other database?You could register them in startup.cs and DI them by using constructor.

Reference：https://stackoverflow.com/a/58022297/11398810

And you could use command `add-migration init -context Context1` to specify the migration and `update-database -context Context1` to update the database in pmc.

Comment: what do you mean *instead of copying*? I **have to** copy - that's the requirement (you'll have to trust me that the requirement makes sense) :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I suggest you go through SQL Server
Because the Role and other tables have the Identity field

Comment: Thank you @Reza for your suggestion. Can you please elaborate? I am aware that the Role and other tables have the Identity field - just not sure how it can be helpful for this?

Comment: You call information from a valid table with a valid ID.
These arguments are also validated in other tables as an external key.
So first cut off the connection between the tables by removing the external key.
Enter the information
[SET IDENTITY_INSERT [YourTableName] ON ]

Enable external key.
If this is the case, you have put the previous correct information in the new tables, which is also valid for the relationship between the tables

Comment: Thanks again, @Reza. The question was specific to Entity Framework - based Identity implementation (sorry if it wasn't clear from the question itself). I am sure you make a very good solution; I just have no idea to what problem. Thanks, anyway - and welcome to Stack Overflow